# ckeditor upload - What parameter(s) do I need to send to method in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, ckeditor

I am working with the ckeditor control in an ASP.NET MVC4 and trying to figure out how to call a method on the controller that will correctly respond to the method that's fired when the "Send to Server" button is clicked on the Upload tab. I would assume that the method would send the file name/path from the box that gets populated with that next to the "Browse" button. But when I create a method on the controller that takes a string parameter, it ends up being "null."

```
//   action on Controller, referenced by setting   
//     filebrowserUploadUrl: '/Uploads/Upload'        
//   in the ckeditor config

public void Upload(string uploadpath)
{
        var blah = uploadpath;  // this is always null...?
}
```

The method is getting called, I have verified that. I just don't know what it's looking for, and can't find any documentation on that.

While there is some pretty decent documentation about the editor itself, I am having trouble finding anything comprehensive or useful about implementing that back end procedures necessary to get it working in .Net MVC. Any advice or assistance anyone can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You Need to get it as `HttpPostedFileBase file` instead of `string uploadpath`. The file parameter will have all the required details like file size, file path etc.,

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly the info I needed to get it working.

Comment: Anytime buddy. Happy Coding.. :)